# Azure storage schema design for Asset Location Tracking

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb, azure-table-storage

I am working to build an Asset Tracking application using Mobile devices that is able to periodically publish its coordinates to an `Event Grid` in Azure.

**Goal**:

1. Track the location of this `Asset` at any given point in time
2. Keep a log of its movement over time for any future analysis
3. Notify the concerned persons when the asset is approaching them say less than 1 Km.
4. Keep the operational cost to minimal.

For this I am planning to create an `Azure function` to first register this device and provide it an `Asset Id` which will be included with the `coordinates` of the event. When the events are raised I want to subscribe to this topic on multiple `Azure function`, one to log the event against the Asset Id, other to query the nearby personal to be notified as the asset approaches. Assuming that the Asset is publishing one event every 15 sec.

I an overly simplifying the schema here, to give an idea of type of information I will be capturing

```
Asset-Info:
  AssetId : String
  AssetType: Integer [Track-Movement= 0 , To-Be-Informed = 1]
  RegisteredAddress : String
  ZipCode : String
  MobileNo: String
  APIKey: String
  CurrentLocation: Point

Asset-Movement:
  MovementId : String
  AssetId : String
  MovementCode: Integer
  StartTime : DateTime
  EndTime : DateTime

Asset-Location:
  AssetId: String
  TimeStamp: DateTime
  Location: Point
```

I am looking for some help around what is the best option for me to store my data in Azure, as there are multiple options like CosmosDB (Document + Table), Azure Table, Data Lake, etc. Can someone please suggest a best storage schema for such a requirement that can minimize my overall running cost. Also how best to shard / partition my schema for best performance.

Comment: you don't really mention what you want to do with the data once you have stored it somewhere -  which is the crucial part to your question. Do you want to query it (regularly)? Or only do batch analytics on it? etc..

Comment: Thanks @silent , I have 2 needs, immediate one is to do a geospatial query to find the other device of a given type `to-be-informed` and send then a notification when a asset enters its neighborhood mostly based on the `CurrentLocaton` in the `Asset-Info`. Second is possibly do a batch analysis to understand the characteristics of each movement  and identify the time and route where it is delayed from expected time.  not really concerned about batch analytics now, just want a timestamp and its location stored. Regards Kiran

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you mention that you mainly want to do geo-spatial querying, I'd recommend to use Cosmos DB for your storage part as it has good support for those queries: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/geospatial

Also, for doing batch analytics - for example in Azure Databricks - there is a Spark connector for Cosmos DB as well: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/spark-connector

Comment: Can you please also help me with best schema to be used, should I use `DocumentDB` or `Table` in CosmosDB. Also would it be cheaper to just push the `AssetLocation` to a blob store as I am not going to use it at a regular interval?

Comment: I would probably go for DocumentDB as it gives you richer query features should you later need it. And yes, of cause you'd be cheaper by just storing everything on blob but then querying it will be dead-slow compared to an index database such as Cosmos DB. Question here is how much data you expect and if Cosmos DB would really get expensive for you. But that's something you need to determine for yourself based on your load profile.

Comment: Thanks! this helps, one last question on this: Can I directly move data from event grid to a document without myself writing a function to append the data?

Comment: not directly but you can for example use Azure Logic Apps to do that basically code-free